# Meta table inefficiencies

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, indexing, metadata

Our database structure leverages the use of a meta table for most of our core objects in this manner:

db_object: id (PRIMARY KEY), field1, field2,...
db_object_meta: id (PRIMARY KEY), object_id, meta_key, meta_value

We've been running for months without any major issues but as of very recently we've experienced some serious latency and our meta tables are the likely culprit due to the size they've grown to ( 500,000 rows+ ).

We mostly query the meta tables in a direct manner such as:

```
SELECT `id` FROM `db_object_meta WHERE `object_id` = 9999

SELECT `meta_key`, `meta_value` FROM `db_object_meta WHERE `object_id` = 9999

SELECT `meta_value` FROM `db_object_meta WHERE `object_id` = 9999 AND `meta_key` = 'key1'
```

It appears to be these types of queries that are getting clogged up and causing a bottleneck. What can be done to improve efficiency?

Would adding an INDEX to the object_id column improve performance, and would this leave all existing queries intact and not needing adjustment?

I've tagged Wordpress because I know it makes profound use of a post meta table.

**CREATE TABLE** (added from comment)

```
CREATE TABLE wm_object_meta (
    id int(32) NOT NULL, 
    store_id int(32) NOT NULL, 
    object_id int(32) NOT NULL, 
    meta_key varchar(64) NOT NULL, 
    meta_value longtext NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    KEY object_id (object_id,meta_key)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Answer (score 1):

An index on object_id might help, it depends on how many distinct object_id values there are in your table.  In general, adding an index to any field used in a where clause has a decent chance of increasing performance.

edit: No, adding an index will not require you to change any existing queries or statements.

Answer (score 1):

Please post `SHOW CREATE TABLE post_meta`; my answer is based on the vague information you provided.

Those three queries need this index on db_object_meta:

```
PRIMARY KEY(object_id, meta_key)
```

And `id` is useless and should be removed.  But that is too much to ask, because it involves too many changes in too many places.

The real problem is that WP uses a "Entity-Attribute-Value" schema design, which sucks at scaling.

Comment: We like having id on the meta rows for precise delete queries, but in hindsight the primary key on this column is useless. This is not actually a WP database, I only included that because they use post_meta for nearly everything so I figured it would be a good tag for meta table efficiency.

Comment: OK.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and can get into more details.  (And I will refrain from bashing WP.  But I may still bash EAV.)  Have you tried my suggested PK?

Comment: CREATE TABLE `wm_object_meta` (
 `id` int(32) NOT NULL,
 `store_id` int(32) NOT NULL,
 `object_id` int(32) NOT NULL,
 `meta_key` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
 `meta_value` longtext NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `object_id` (`object_id`,`meta_key`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

Comment: Where does `store_id` fit into the picture?  Is `(object_id, meta_key)` "unique"?  Or do you need 3 columns to get "unique" `(store_id, object_id, meta_key)`?